# How to bind file type with blob image directly using Spring

Tags: java, spring, image, blob

```
                            private Blob image;
                            public Blob getImage() {
                             return image;
                                }

                             public void setImage(Blob image) {
                             this.image = image;
                              }
```

this is the blob image object

```
                                                    <label class="col-md-4                                        control-label" for="file">
                                Upload Image:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <sf:input id="file" name="file"
                                     type="file" placeholder="" path="file"
                                    class="form-control input-md" />
```

This is the jsp page

```
                    @RequestMapping(value = "/changeImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getChangeImage() {




    return "Editprofile";
}
```

This is the controller method. In this method i want to get the upload file and convert it to Blob image. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.upload = function() {
  var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0], r = new FileReader();
      r.onloadend = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;

        }
      r.readAsBinaryString(f);
```

Comment: <input type='file' accept="image/*" id="file" file-model="file"/>